# Cannot trigger an exception within an lambda expression

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I am somewhat new to Java 8 and am trying to throw a an exception within an lambda expression as following: if subQty is less than min or greater than max, in this case, my unit test calculated min/max to be 182 and 255, and I am submitting a subQty of 10, therefore it should raise an exception and fail this unit test. However, I am keep getting the green light why is that?

```
public void verifyingIndividualSubmissionValueLimits(String alias, double min, double max)
    // ... some code here ...

    // Get local stock price
    CompletableFuture<Double> localPriceFuture = instrumentRequester.getMidPrice(instId);

    // Calculate the min and max quantity
    localPriceFuture.thenAcceptBoth(dollarFxRateFuture,
            (localPrice, fxRate) -> {
                double minLocalValue = min * fxRate;
                double maxLocalValue = max * fxRate;
                long minQuantity = Math.round(minLocalValue / localPrice);
                long maxQuantity = Math.round(maxLocalValue / localPrice);
                if (subQty < minQuantity || subQty > maxQuantity) {
                    log.debug("We should throw an exception because subQty is {}", subQty);
                    throw new SubmissionValidationException(String.format("Quantity: %s, is not within %s and %s", subQty, minQuantity, maxQuantity));
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: what unit test? Have you debugged your test to see whether your flow executes what you think it does?

Comment: @ArMonk - Could you please share code which you have written into test case. That would be helpful for others to understand what you are trying. Please debug the code and see whether control is going to into if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You throws exception in different thread. You are creating a thread that calculate min, max rate and throws an exception but exception occurs in thread so you can not see any exception in main thread (in this case `verifyingIndividualSubmissionValueLimits`). You can read callback and async threads here https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/

Comment: The function passed to `thenAcceptBoth` may get evaluated within the caller thread, that’s unpredictable. What’s more important, is that the exception doesn’t get propagated to the caller even when being thrown within the same thread. It will be caught and used for completing the future exceptionally. But the OP doesn’t check the state and not even wait for the completion, so it’s also possible that the unit test ended even before the evaluation got to that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can only throw exception from inside the lambda only if the @**FunctionInterface** it represent is throwing exception, Otherwise you will have to handle it inside the lambda only, for example this can be achieved creating your own **FunctionalInterface** -

```
public class Test {

    public void foo(Fun f) throws Exception {
        f.apply();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface Fun{
        void apply() throws Exception;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.foo(() -> {
           throw new Exception();
        });
    }
}
```

In your case you are using CompletableFuture thenAcceptBoth function which use **BiConsumer** function interface which does not throw any exception, so it's not possible to throw it from there.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface BiConsumer<T, U> {
    void accept(T t, U u);
    ....
}
```

These are compile time restrictions and valid even if it's not in a separate thread.